# week number from given date in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with two columns Date and value.
I want to add new column named week_number that basically is how many weeks back from the  given date

`import pandas as pd`
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','value'])`

`df['Date'] = [ '04-02-2019','03-02-2019','28-01-2019','20-01-2019']`

`df['value'] = [10,20,30,40]`

`df`
         Date  value
0  04-02-2019     10
1  03-02-2019     20
2  28-01-2019     30
3  20-01-2019     40

suppose given date is 05-02-2019.
Then I need to add a column week_number in a way such that how many weeks back the Date column date is from given date.
The output should be

```
    Date  value   week_number
```

0  04-02-2019     10    1
1  03-02-2019     20    1
2  28-01-2019     30    2
3  20-01-2019     40    3

how can I do this in pandas

Answer (score 5):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True`, then subtract from right side by [`rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rsub.html), convert `timedelta`s to [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), get modulo by `7` and add `1`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['week_number'] = df['Date'].rsub(pd.Timestamp('2019-02-05')).dt.days // 7 + 1
#alternative 
#df['week_number'] = (pd.Timestamp('2019-02-05') - df['Date']).dt.days // 7 + 1
print (df)
        Date  value  week_number
0 2019-02-04     10            1
1 2019-02-03     20            1
2 2019-01-28     30            2
3 2019-01-20     40            3
```